# Where does values of argument `timestamp` of quantstrat::ruleSignal's come from?

Tags: quantstrat

When reading source code of [ruleSignal](https://github.com/R-Finance/quantstrat/blob/master/R/ruleSignal.R), argument `timestamp` at line 66 is a very important input, but I could not figure out where `timestamp` data come from.

It seems that functions `add.indicator`, `add.signal`, `add.rule`, `applyIndicators`, `applySignals`, which run before `ruleSignal` don't use or generate `timestamps` values.

I wonder which function generates values of `timestamp` for `ruleSignal` to use, or where data of `timestamp` come from.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brian Peterson's reply which answers my question:

> indicators and signals are always presumed to be vectorized, per the
>   documentation, so no timestamp is required.
>
> rules, by default, are path dependent, and thus need a timestamp to
>   operate from.
>
> The path-dependent loop is outside of the individual rule function.
>   see line 555 of rules.R